# Where am I going wrong? Selecting results that are not in a sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tbl_inspectors 
WHERE user_id NOT IN 
(Select user_id FROM dbo.vw_alerts WHERE alertID=1)
```

Am trying to return a list of Inspectors that have not read a specific alert, user_id being the common field, the logic of the statement seems to work, but no results are returned. Though the subquery does return results if run alone.

Comment: Check your data, are there any inspectors who have actually not read specific alert?

Comment: I am a relative n00b Ravi, but not that bad :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `NOT IN`, then you should only include values that are not null because `not in` handles `null` values differently:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tbl_inspectors 
WHERE user_id NOT IN (Select user_id 
                      FROM dbo.vw_alerts 
                      WHERE alertID=1
                        AND user_id is not null)
```

See [NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: Many thanks, simple solution and increases my understanding too, cheers

Comment: @DuncanCook you are welcome, that article is a great reference and it is written by a StackOverflow member. :)

Answer (score 0):

But the subquery results are the ones you don't want. So if the subquery is returning all users then your query won't return any results. Are you sure that it should be returning rows - there are users who haven't responded to the alarm.

Comment: yeah even if everyone had read the alert there are still users (archived, inactive etc) that have not read it, the answer above solves it.